# Can't get sound to play

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to use star wars opening crawl on my website. I've found the right example 
http://codepen.io/SirDaev/pen/vLLwzw 
There is no sound. According to the author sound should be displayed with the text and here goes the problem. There is no sound when i copy the whole code on my website. I' using child template of wordpress 16

```js
var sWidth; //screen width
var sHeight; //screen height
var canvas;
var context;
var numOfStars;
var starDensity = 1800; //lower == more stars
var starColors = ["#111", "#333", "#555", "#7872a8", "#483f26"];
var audio = $('audio').get(0);

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Play the theme song
  setTimeout(function() {
    audio.play();
  }, 7600);
  
  //Get the window size
 sWidth = $(window).width();
 sHeight = $(window).height();
  
  //Get the canvas
  canvas = $('#starfield');
  
  //Fill out the canvas
 canvas.attr('height', sHeight);
 canvas.attr('width', sWidth);
 context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  
  //Calculate the number of stars
  numOfStars = Math.floor((sWidth * sHeight) / starDensity);
  console.log(numOfStars);
  
  //Draw the stars
  function stars() {
    for (i=0;i<numOfStars;i++) {
      //Get a random star color
      var starColor = starColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)];
      //Get a random x-position
      var starX = Math.floor(Math.random()*sWidth);
      //Get a random y-position
      var starY = Math.floor(Math.random()*sHeight);
      //Draw
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(starX, starY, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = starColor;
      context.fill();
    }
  }
  
  //Draw the stars
  stars();
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1080px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

/* In case of no audio support */
audio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#starfield {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: starfield 0s 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes starfield {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.long-time {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00d7ff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 51%;
  width: 65%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  animation: long-time 5s 1s forwards;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .long-time {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes long-time {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  18% { opacity: 1; }
  82% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.logo {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  animation: logo 10s 8s cubic-bezier(0,.1,.2,1); forwards;
}

@keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { width: 40px;
         opacity: 0; }
}

.crawl-container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350vh;
  max-height: 3000px;
  /**/color: #ffe029;
  /**/text-align: justify;
  /**/overflow: hidden;
  /**/transform-origin: 50% 100%;/**/
  /**/transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(16deg);
  /**/animation: crawl-container 0s 17s forwards;
}

@keyframes crawl-container {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.crawl-container .crawl {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: crawl 170s 17s linear forwards;
}

.crawl p {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 10%;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.crawl p.title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.crawl p.title-1 {
  margin-bottom: .7em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 img {
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
}

p.crawl-p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 5.6vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  p.crawl-p {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes crawl {
  to { top: -250%; }
}
```

```html
<audio preload="auto">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<canvas id="starfield"></canvas>
 <div class="long-time">A long time ago in a galaxy far,<br />far away....</div>
<img class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/star-wars-7-logo.png" />
<div class="crawl-container">
  <div class="crawl">
      <p class="title title-1">Episode VII</p>
      <p class="title title-2"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/the-force-awakens.png"</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Luke Skywalker has vanished. In his absence, the sinister FIRST ORDER has risen from the ashes of the Empire and will not rest until Skywalker, the last Jedi, has been destroyed.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">With the support of the REPUBLIC, General Leia Organa leads a brave RESISTANCE. She is desperate to find her brother Luke and gain his help in restoring peace and justice to the galaxy.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Leia has sent her most daring pilot on a secret mission to Jakku, where an old ally has discovered a clue to Luke's whereabouts....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you referencing jquery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you miss autoplay feature of audio tag on HTML 5 ,

allways try that first ..

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 0):

The audio isn't played. To play the audio instantly, use the [`autoplay`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp) attribute on the `audio` tag.

```
<audio preload="auto" autoplay>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Working snippet:

```js
var sWidth; //screen width
var sHeight; //screen height
var canvas;
var context;
var numOfStars;
var starDensity = 1800; //lower == more stars
var starColors = ["#111", "#333", "#555", "#7872a8", "#483f26"];
var audio = $('audio').get(0);

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Play the theme song
  setTimeout(function() {
    audio.play();
  }, 7600);
  
  //Get the window size
 sWidth = $(window).width();
 sHeight = $(window).height();
  
  //Get the canvas
  canvas = $('#starfield');
  
  //Fill out the canvas
 canvas.attr('height', sHeight);
 canvas.attr('width', sWidth);
 context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  
  //Calculate the number of stars
  numOfStars = Math.floor((sWidth * sHeight) / starDensity);
  console.log(numOfStars);
  
  //Draw the stars
  function stars() {
    for (i=0;i<numOfStars;i++) {
      //Get a random star color
      var starColor = starColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)];
      //Get a random x-position
      var starX = Math.floor(Math.random()*sWidth);
      //Get a random y-position
      var starY = Math.floor(Math.random()*sHeight);
      //Draw
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(starX, starY, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = starColor;
      context.fill();
    }
  }
  
  //Draw the stars
  stars();
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 1080px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

/* In case of no audio support */
audio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#starfield {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: starfield 0s 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes starfield {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.long-time {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00d7ff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 51%;
  width: 65%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  animation: long-time 5s 1s forwards;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .long-time {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes long-time {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  18% { opacity: 1; }
  82% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.logo {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  animation: logo 10s 8s cubic-bezier(0,.1,.2,1); forwards;
}

@keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  98% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { width: 40px;
         opacity: 0; }
}

.crawl-container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350vh;
  max-height: 3000px;
  /**/color: #ffe029;
  /**/text-align: justify;
  /**/overflow: hidden;
  /**/transform-origin: 50% 100%;/**/
  /**/transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(16deg);
  /**/animation: crawl-container 0s 17s forwards;
}

@keyframes crawl-container {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.crawl-container .crawl {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: crawl 170s 17s linear forwards;
}

.crawl p {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 10%;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.crawl p.title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.crawl p.title-1 {
  margin-bottom: .7em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.crawl p.title-2 img {
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
}

p.crawl-p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 5.6vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  p.crawl-p {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@keyframes crawl {
  to { top: -250%; }
}
```

```html
<audio preload="auto" autoplay>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/sw-7-theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<canvas id="starfield"></canvas>
 <div class="long-time">A long time ago in a galaxy far,<br />far away....</div>
<img class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/star-wars-7-logo.png" />
<div class="crawl-container">
  <div class="crawl">
      <p class="title title-1">Episode VII</p>
      <p class="title title-2"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331813/the-force-awakens.png"</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Luke Skywalker has vanished. In his absence, the sinister FIRST ORDER has risen from the ashes of the Empire and will not rest until Skywalker, the last Jedi, has been destroyed.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">With the support of the REPUBLIC, General Leia Organa leads a brave RESISTANCE. She is desperate to find her brother Luke and gain his help in restoring peace and justice to the galaxy.</p>
      <p class="crawl-p">Leia has sent her most daring pilot on a secret mission to Jakku, where an old ally has discovered a clue to Luke's whereabouts....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you change something ? Code is so long, it doesn't seem to be relevent to post the whole code in the answer...

Comment: @Random Sorry, I'll edit the answer. It should be in the `audio` tag.

Comment: Everything goes smoothly now.
I just want to thank all of you. You have right, I didn't add the the autoplay attribute, which was relevant :)